# Linq group by producing duplicates using Max

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following data:

```
DATE       TYPE CUST     PRAC    CUTR        ACTI
2018-02-22,HOME,9481    ,10     ,29204.0    ,QUS
2018-02-22,HOME,9481    ,23     ,39204.0    ,QUS
2018-02-22,HOME,9481    ,64     ,29204.0    ,QUS
2018-02-25,HOME,9481    ,35     ,49533.0    ,QUS
2018-02-25,HOME,9481    ,52     ,29452.0    ,QUS
2018-02-25,HOME,9481    ,52     ,29446.0    ,QUS
2018-02-25,HOME,9481    ,25     ,29532.0    ,QUS
2018-02-27,HOME,9481    ,52     ,29665.0    ,QUS
2018-02-27,HOME,9481    ,45     ,29664.0    ,QUS

2018-02-21,HOME,7540    ,53     ,29205.0    ,QUS
2018-02-22,HOME,7540    ,35     ,39205.0    ,QUS
```

In the above data there are two customers: 9841 and 7540.

I need to select the record with the newest DATE.  Once I have the record with the newest date, then it should select the record with the highest CUTR value.

This is the linq I have so far:

```
List<clsCustomer> lstCustomer = (from row in lstCustomer
                                 group row by row.cust into g
                                 let maxDate = g.Max(r => r.date)
                                 from rowGroup in g
                                 where rowGroup.date == maxDate
                                 select rowGroup).ToList();
```

The following are the results returned:

```
DATE       TYPE CUST     PRAC    CUTR        ACTI
2018-02-27,HOME,9481    ,52     ,29665.0    ,QUS
2018-02-27,HOME,9481    ,45     ,29664.0    ,QUS
2018-02-22,HOME,7540    ,35     ,39205.0    ,QUS
```

Notice there are two rows returned for customer 9481.  It should only have returned one record per customer.  (latest date, THEN highest CUTR).

This should be the correct results returned.  Notice it should get the latest date for each customer.  Then from that results, get the highest CUTR:

```
DATE       TYPE CUST     PRAC    CUTR        ACTI
2018-02-27,HOME,9481    ,52     ,29665.0    ,QUS
2018-02-22,HOME,7540    ,35     ,39205.0    ,QUS
```

I am almost there but cannot figure out how to remove the extra row.  Any help would be appreciated.

**ANSWER**

Thank you habib and everyone for the answer:

```
var lstCustomer = (from row in lstCustomer
                   group row by row.cust into g
                   let maxDate = g.Max(r => r.date)
                   select g.Where(e => e.date == maxDate).OrderByDescending(e => e.cutr)
                   .FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: You forgot the `cutr` clause. You already do `from rowGroup in g where rowGroup.date == maxDate select rowGroup`, just add one more such statement for `cutr`. And in case you need only one line even though there may be 2 with the same CUTR, add `.Take(5)`

Comment: Use OrderByDescending using date then take first item : List<clsCustomer> lstCustomer =  row.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.date)
    .GroupBy(x => x.cust)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();

Comment: The problem is that it is not necessarily the highest CUTR for that customer.  It has to always be the newest DATE.  (Then highest CUTR for that date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You forgot the cutr clause. You already do from rowGroup in g where
>   rowGroup.date == maxDate select rowGroup, just add one more such
>   statement for cutr. And in case you need only one line even though
>   there may be 2 with the same CUTR.
>   @Mike Makarov

```
var lstCustomer  = from a in lstCustomer
                group a by a.cust into g
                let maxDate = g.Max(r => r.date)
                select g.Where(e => e.date == maxDate).OrderByDescending(e => e.cutr)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Hopefully it will workds

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting a condition on the CUTR column, you are just getting the rows with MAXDATE condition which gives two rows in this example.

you should replace your query as follows:
    from row in lstCustomer
    group row by row.cust into g
    let maxDate = g.Max(r => r.date)
    let maxCUTR = g.Max(r => r.CUTR)
    from rowGroup in g
    where rowGroup.date == maxDate && rowGroup.CUTR == maxCUTR
    select rowGroup

Comment: Your response does max(CUTR) over entire `rowgroup`, that's not what he asked for. He wanted to do first max(date), then, on the date filter, max (cutr).